# Model name of objects in django templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Is there any way to get the model name of any objects in django templates. Manually, we can try it by defining methods in models or using template tags... But is there any built-in way?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`object.__class__.__name__` or `object._meta.object_name` should give you the name of the model class. However, this **cannot be used in templates** because the attribute names start with an underscore.

There isn't a built in way to get at that value from the templates, so you'll have to define a model method that returns that attribute, or for a more generic/reusable solution, use a template filter:

```
@register.filter
def to_class_name(value):
    return value.__class__.__name__
```

which you can use in your template as:

```
{{ obj | to_class_name }}
```

Comment: Ok.. Thanks Shawn for reply.I used this way, thought may be some built-in way!!

Comment: I don't think the need for it is common enough to warrant a built-in approach. If you need it often enough, you could create an Abstract class that implements the method then use it as a base for all your models. Personally though, I'd stick to using a filter tag.

Comment: Add filter file in `your_app/templatetags` directory, naming as `to_class_name.py`. And you have to restart Django after you added filter. Don't forget to `{% load to_class_name %}` in your template.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot access the class name directly. Doing something like this:

```
{{ object.__class__ }}
```

will cause a `TemplateSyntaxError: Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores`. Django doesn't let you access those sorts of attributes - Python conventions means they are hidden implementation details, not part of the object's API.

Create a template filter instead, and then you can use it as follows:

```
{{ object|model_name_filter }}
```

Creating filters is very easy: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 4):

Django added a publicly accessible API to model options called _meta, but you still can't access variables with an underscore in the template. Use a template filter:

```
@register.filter
def verbose_name(instance):
    return instance._meta.verbose_name
```

In the template:

```
{{ instance|verbose_name }}
```

I even like to chain the `title` filter to capitalize the words in the my template:

```
{{ instance|verbose_name|title }}
```

Comment: This results in `'str' object has no attribute '_meta'`

Comment: You don't have a model instance then. You have a str that you are applying the filter to, which doesn't have such an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Since 1.2 version and may be early Django has an attribute `opts` into templates. The atribute is link to `model._meta` For evidence you should [look at source code into Github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.2/django/contrib/admin/actions.py)

It used into template very simple: `{{opts}}` or `{{opts.db_table}}`

Comment: That's for django-admin only.

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily access the content type of the page, this way you don't even need to poke into the `specific`:

```
{% if pub.content_type.app_labeled_name == 'home | publication' %}
    {% include "home/publication.html" with pub=pub.specific %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as `pub` is not defined, and `.content_type` does not appear on a model.

Answer (score 0):

This answer demonstrates a practical use case. In my app each model has a generic.CreateView named name=”<model>-create” in urls.py; namespaced/referenced as {% url <app>:<model>-create %} in those templates which need to link to it. Each model has a generic.ListView rendered by <app>/templates/<app>/<model>_list.html. I wanted to include a button at the bottom of each rendered list view to link to the corresponding create view. To ensure consistency across multiple list views I wanted to do this in a base template which each list view template could extend upon. **To do this I needed to be able to reference the model name in a template.** Here’s how I did it.

```
$ mkdir <app>/templatetags
$ touch <app>/templatetags/__init__.py
$ vi <app>/templatetags/tags.py

from django import template
register = template.Library()
# this filter allows any template to reference an instance’s model name as <instance>|class_name
@register.filter(name="class_name")
def class_name(instance):
    return instance._meta.model.__name__

$ vi <app>/templates/base_list.html

~
{% with name=object_list|first|class_name|lower %}
        <button onclick="location.href='{% url request.resolver_match.app_name|add:':'|add:name|add:'-create' %}';" title="create"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
{% endwith  %}
```

** substitute <app>, <model>, and <instance> for your own names.*