# How to use __repr__ method within django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

For example, there is an object in a nested loop:

```
 {% for fieldset in inline_admin_form %}
                    {% for line in fieldset %}
                      {% for field in line %}

                        {% if field.is_hidden %} {{ field.field }} {% endif %}
                      {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endfor %}
              {% endif %}
```

Now I want to check the class name and some information about `field.field`, so I use `field.field.__repr__()` to replace `field.field`.

However, the django template complains about it after the change:

```
Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'field.field.__repr__'
```

Does anyone have idea about this? And is there any better way to debug for a variable in django template? (I tried `{% debug %}` but found it awful when I want to check a variable in a nested loop..)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571649/model-name-of-objects-in-django-templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily write a template filter which allows you to do `{{ var|asrepr }}`. See the documentation, but it'll look something like this:

```
@register.filter
def asrepr(value):
    return repr(value)
```

Answer (score 24):

```
{{ value|stringformat:'r' }}
```

uses the string `%` operator style formatting with the `r` format which uses `repr()`