# How to get class in django template

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to get an objects class in the django template? Something like:

```
{{ obj.__class__ }}
```

?

Comment: What is `obj`? If it's a model, you could add a `def get_class_name(self): return self.__class__` method and call {{ obj.get_class_name }} from your template. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571649/model-name-of-objects-in-django-templates

Comment: I'm wondering how did you come to need to retrieve the class of an object in a template. It feels like a bad design to me, even though you can do it with a template tag

Comment: @MihaiZamfir I have a concatenated list, and I need to know the type of object it is to generate the correct url for that object.

Comment: wouldn't be better to make two lists in your view and pass them to ur template? or if you can't split the list, make a list of tuples, the second item indicating the type. But it's just a personal preference of course, do as you wish. I like to limit my number of custom tags/filters as much as I can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't call any attribute that start with underescore. Create a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) will help you

```
 @register.filter
 def get_class(obj):
     return obj.__class__
```

use

```
{{ obj|get_class }}
```

Answer (score 4):

It would be nice to have this as a built-in to django, but I used a templatetag here instead:

```
@register.filter
def to_class_name(value):
    return value.__class__.__name__
```

And in the template:

```
{{ obj|to_class_name }}
```