# How to get the name of a class model in template django

Tags: django, django-models, django-class-based-views

This question is similar to this question ([Model name of objects in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571649/model-name-of-objects-in-django-templates)) but not the same.

I want to know how gets the Models class name (in this case 'Apple'), or at the very least return a string that I can pass over.

Model.py

```
   django.db import models
   class Apple(models.Model):
      .....
```

apple.html

```
 <p>Sorry, no {{ ***Model class name**** }}</p>
```

An example in the browser::: "
 Sorry, no Apple
"

**EDIT**

Some extra conditions:

1. What if there is no object created from the model, hence the 'Sorry, no apples'
2. How to kind this flexible so you can use the same template for any kind of fruit.

Comment: Can you clarify in what way your question is different? For example, if you are passing an instance of `Apple` then `apple.__class__.__name__` will give you `"Apple"`.

Comment: Sure, no problem. There are two issues that I would like to cover:
1. If the is no objects of that model. I know that sounds weird, but if you wanted to have a listview for apples but there are no apples, hence the 'Sorry, no apple'.
2. If you want to reuse the template for multiple models, eg. pear/pineapple/banana/etc.

I hope this help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're passing an object to your template, and you want to do this processing in the template and not in the views, one approach is to create the following [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
@register.filter
def get_class(value):
    return value.__class__.__name__
```

and get the name with

`{{apple|get_class}}`